# how to use multiple queries in java using jdbc

Tags: jdbc

how to use multiple queries in java using jdbc

1.how to use this below query in the method without deleting the already existing query in
  method

1. Insert into item_details(stock_name,temple,quantity)
    SELECT a.stock_name, a.temple, SUM(Case when Type='purchase' then quantity else
     (quantity*-1) End) AS quantity
    FROM purchase_details a
    GROUP BY a.stock_name, a.temple

   ---

   ```
      public boolean insertIntimationDetails(StockForm ofform) {
      boolean status=false;
      PreparedStatement pst=null;
      Connection conn=null;

      try {
      System.out.println("Inside insertIntimationDetails ");
        String query=" update purchase_details set intimation_quantity = ? where                 
    temple=? and Stock_name=? ";       
       System.out.println(query);
       conn=getConnection();
       System.out.println(query);
       pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
       System.out.println(ofform.getIntimationQuantity());
       pst.setString(2, ofform.getForTemple());
       pst.setString(3, ofform.getStockName());
       pst.setLong(1, ofform.getIntimationQuantity());

                   int rows= pst.executeUpdate();
       if(rows>0){
           status=true;
       } 



       } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }   finally{
       try {
           if(pst!=null)
               pst.close();
           if(conn!=null)
               conn.close();
       } catch (Exception e2) {
           e2.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   return status;

       }
   ```

Comment: Seems like you need to have transactional property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the two SQLs atomic by using something similar to below code. This guarantees all or nothing rule.

```
public boolean insertIntimationDetails(StockForm ofform) {
    boolean status = false;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Connection conn = null;
            Statement stat = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("Inside insertIntimationDetails ");
        String query = " update purchase_details set intimation_quantity = ? where temple=? and Stock_name=? ";
        System.out.println(query);
        conn = getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false); // Disable Auto Commit
        System.out.println(query);
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        System.out.println(ofform.getIntimationQuantity());
        pst.setString(2, ofform.getForTemple());
        pst.setString(3, ofform.getStockName());
        pst.setLong(1, ofform.getIntimationQuantity());

        int rows = pst.executeUpdate();
        if (rows > 0) {
            status = true;
        }

        stat = conn.createStatement();
        boolean status2 = stat
                .execute("Insert into item_details(stock_name,temple,quantity) SELECT a.stock_name, a.temple, SUM(Case when Type='purchase' then quantity else (quantity*-1) End) AS quantity FROM purchase_details a GROUP BY a.stock_name, a.temple");

        if (status && status2) {
            conn.commit();
        } else {
            conn.rollback();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        conn.rollback();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (pst != null)
                pst.close();
            if (stat != null)
                stat.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return status;

}
```